# How to open an CSV file that was input by user - python?

Tags: python

Based on the image, as you can see I had to hardcode the csv file to open and read/write the csv file. How do I replace the hardcoded CSV file to user input? sys.argv ?

[HARDCODE CSV FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVQAq.png)

Comment: What have you already tried? And please include the code in your post as a code block (with ` ``` ` on the lines before and after), not an image, so we can look at it more easily.

Comment: sys,arg is option where you can define file path in exec and then writing a function to print that , else during execution you can directly ask for the file path and then do processing, but using sys.argv is better option

Answer (score 0):

Take file name as input.
Then read CSV and store in cname
Access the same

```
file1= input ("Enter name of file")
cname=csv.reader(file1)
companyCSVFile=csv.reader(cname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read this tutorial first: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

use `sys.argv` array to access arguments passed.

call you to script like this
`python test.py your_file_name.csv`

access:

```py
import sys.argv

print(sys.argv[1])
```